# Assign a score to a word in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sublist

I have a dictionary and a list with sublist with words:

```
d={"love":3, "good":2}
l=[["love", "apple", "same"],["good", "GOOD", "year"]]
```

If the word in the list is not in dictionary keys I need to assign a value of 3 to that word and sum the value of the sublist. 
In the example the outcome of the values would be:

```
[6, 3]
```

I have tried this code:

```
def scoring():
    score1=[]
    for sublst in l:
        for val in sublst:
            if val.lower() not in d.get(val.lower(), 0):
                score1=sum(3 for val in sublst)
        print(score1)
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Try `[sum(3 for j in i if j.lower() not in d) for i in l]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following list comprehension will provide the expected result:

```
>>> [sum(3 if w.lower() not in d else 0 for w in sl) for sl in l]
[6, 3]
```

To correct the function in your question:

```
def scoring():
    score1=[]
    for sublst in salida_tweets_separado:
        s = 0
        for val in sublst:
            if val.lower() not in valores:
                s += 3
        score1.append(s)
    print(score1)
```